# Obtain single field data Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to get a single form value from a posted form using HTML and Jquery could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong with the following script.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="target" action="1.html">
<input type="text" value="Hello world">
<input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
<script>

$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {

var input = $("#target :input[text]"); 
  alert( input);
  console.log(input)

  event.preventDefault();

});
</script>";


</body>
</html>
```

I can only seem to return an object but I cant display this using alert or the console.log feature.

Answer (score 2):

```
var input = $("#target :input[text]");
```

should be:

```
var input = $("#target input[type='text']").val();
```

Comment: Or `$("#target :text")`

Comment: True, I just like doing all attribute matching with `[attr="val"]` .  But yours is totally valid @A.Wolff

Comment: Anyway `input[type='text']` is more performant but not sure it does really matter here ;)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your submit event in ready function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {

    var input = $("#target input[text]").val(); 
    alert( input);
    console.log(input)

    event.preventDefault();

  });
});
```

Comment: It's not needed in this example because the form is in the DOM before the handler is attached.